# Run WMI Process Unelevated

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, wmi

I'm using WMI to run processes from my C# app, which runs as admin. And so the process I run, runs as admin too, which I don't want.

Can I run the process unelevated or in the user's normal privileges? I can get the username from the env variable `%username%` but in order to run processes as a different user, WMI requires both the username & password in the connection options.

Comment: You might be able to create a service that runs as admin, which then uses IPC or port communication to provide the results.  A bit more complex but it is a way to keep admin priveleges out of your application.

Comment: That's overkill but thanks for responding. My app is portable so it can't use services easily.